# Best wat to create npm module with some initial name

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am working on nodejs module. I am using NAPI for creating nodejs module.
Suppose my module name is hello.
so it will be used in javascript as

```
require("hello")
```

but I want to require these like this

```
require("Name/hello");
```

One way is by creating module by name `Name/hello`.
Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

Sort of depends on what you're trying to achieve.

There is the idea of package namespaces, such as @babel where you have packages like @babel/core etc. But then you get multiple npm packages.

You can also look into libraries like lodash which exports both lodash as well as lodash/groupBy from the same package. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40053510/4707926 for how that works.